# Unterminated &lt;c:set tag - JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am getting the error "Unterminated <c:set tag - JSTL"

**Code:**

```
<c:set var="p" value="${entity.metadata().type().name()}${entity.metadata().type().version().toString().replace(".", "_")}"> </c:set>
```

I tried -

```
<c:set var="p" value="${entity.metadata().type().name()}${entity.metadata().type().version().toString().replace(".", "_")}"/>
```

too.

Comment: Did you add `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>` in your JSP?

Comment: Yes I added -> <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>     I am able to use <c:forEach items="${documentEntities}" var="entity"> with out any problem

Comment: I am not JEE expert but are you sure that `entity.metadata().type().name()` is proper syntax in EL (at least in JSP)? Or `toString().replace(".", "_")`?

Comment: Have you tried with some simpler case like `<c:set var="p" value="x"/>`?

Comment: Or maybe use simple *expression* `<%=...%>` instead of EL like `<c:set var="p" value="<%=entity.metadata().type().name()%><%=entity.metadata().type().version().toString().replace(".", "_")%>"/>`

Comment: Pshemo - I read at many place in SO that <% tags are deprecated. So have not take that route.  I used the value with out passing it to a variable and it worked. I wanted to use the value at many places, so thought of passing it to a variable for using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you use quotation marks is confusing for the parser. Once it meets the second `"`, it assumes it to be the end of the tag, hence the exception.
Try this:

```
<c:set var="p" value="${entity.metadata().type().name()}${entity.metadata().type().version().toString().replace('.', '_')}">
```