# c:set jstl tag confuses parser

Tags: java, jstl

I have a c:set tag that throws an unterminated tag error (related question [Unterminated &lt;c:set tag - JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104819/unterminated-ltcset-tag-jstl)). The related question's answer states that this is a parser error but I am not sure how I can fix it in this case.

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${cssinclist}">
    <c:set var="stylesheetFile" value="<tiles:insertAttribute value="${item}" flush="true" />" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/${ stylesheetFile }"/>" />
</c:forEach>
<c:remove var="stylesheetFile" />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use "**item**" variable? Try this:

```
<c:set var="stylesheetFile" value="${item}"/>
```